# How to get all ISO 10646 characters with U+00A0 and higher

Tags: javascript

I want to get all valid characters to be used as the name of class in CSS. How can I get all ISO 10646 characters with U+00A0 and higher in Javascript?

Comment: Letters are represented as numbers right? `'\u00A0'.charCodeAt(0) // 160` Would checking values above that work?

Comment: do you want to get a list of them or just how to test if a class is valid ?

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli I want to get an array with those utf-8 code in it

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

https://codepen.io/Caaat1/pen/JjrajPx

REM: You may have to wait a few seconds for the output due to a sufficient amount of the data.

```js
for (i = -1; ++i < 256;)
  for ((d = document).body.append(t = d.createElement('TABLE')), j = -2; ++j < 16;)
    for (
      k = -1,
      t.append(r = d.createElement('TR'));
      r.appendChild(d.createElement('TD')).innerHTML =
        j < 0
          ? k < 0 ? i.toString(16).padStart(2, 0) : k.toString(16)
          : k < 0 ? j.toString(16) : String.fromCharCode(i * 256 + j * 16 + k),
      ++k < 16;
    );
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: monospace;
  margin: 2% auto;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
tr:first-child td:first-child {
  border: 0;
}
tr:first-child,
td:first-child {
  color: red;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: end;
}
```